# Securing Socket.io

Tags: node.js, authentication, ssl, websocket, socket.io

I am using a Node.js based https server that authenticates using HTTP Basic (which is fine as the data are sent over the SSL encrypted connection).

Now I want to provide a Socket.io connection which should be

1. encrypted and
2. for authenticated users only.

The question is how to do this. I already found out that I need to specify `{ secure: true }` in the client JavaScript code when connecting to the socket, but how do I force on the server-side that socket connections can only be run over SSL, and that it works only for authenticated users?

I guess that the SSL thing is the easy part, as the Socket.io server is bound to the https server only, so it should run using SSL only, and there should be no possibility to run it over an (additionally) running http server, right?

Regarding the other thing I have not the slightest idea of how to ensure that socket connections can only be established once the user successfully authenticated using HTTP Basic.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you just use the wss protocol instead of the standard ws protocol to encrypt communications over the wire? Also, what do you mean by authenticating the user? Do you mean authenticating sent user credentials against credentials in a DB?

Comment: I did not find relevant documentation about how to secure a socket in socket.io (beside implementing SSL on the server itself). 1) Could I ask an example of where to put the flag `{secure: true}` when wanting to make the channel secure from the client please? 2) Also, does this flag mean that the message FROM client TO server will be encrypted? or what does this flag essentially do? 
3) Lastly, is there a way to block the node app or the connection to a client if a socket/channel is not secure? Many thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although the answer by Linus is basically right, I now solved it in a more easy way using the [session.socket.io](https://github.com/wcamarao/session.socket.io) - which basically does the same thing, but with way less custom-code to write.

Answer (score 23):

**Edit:** Of course OP is right in their other answer; what's more, with socket.io >1.0 you might use [socket.io-express-session](https://github.com/xpepermint/socket.io-express-session).

Original answer:

Socket.io supports authorization via the `io.set('authorization', callback)` mechanism. See the relevant documentation: [Authorizing](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Authorizing). Here's a simple example (this authenticates using a cookie-based session, and a connect/express session store -- if you need something else, you just implement another 'authorization' handler):

```
var utils = require('connect').utils;

// Set up a session store of some kind
var sessionId = 'some id';
var sessionStore = new MemoryStore();
// Make express app use the session store
app.use(express.session({store: sessionStore, key: sessionId});

io.configure(function () {
    io.set('authorization', function (handshakeData, callback) {
        var cookie = utils.parseCookie(handshakeData.headers.cookie);

        if(!(sessionId in cookie)) {
            return callback(null, false);
        }

        sessionStore.get(cookie[sessionId], function (err, session) {
            if(err) {
                return callback(err);
            }

            if(!('user' in session)) {
                return callback(null, false);
            }

            // This is an authenticated user!
            // Store the session on handshakeData, it will be available in connection handler
            handshakeData.session = session;

            callback(null, true);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Setting the socket to be secured is done by:

   - setting the secure flag - as you wrote ({secure: true})
   - OR by using https protocol when creating the server (instead of http) - which will set the secure flag to be true automatically
2. Good lib that simplify the authentication process is: https://github.com/auth0/socketio-jwt