# Why socket-io 's get is not able to get data from persistent session?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

Here I am using get of socket-io and on every page reload it is giving me new values ( Ideally it should come from session and should be same ). Can you please point-out the reason?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var _ = require('lodash');
var q = require('q');

server.listen(3000);

var userCounter = 0;
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.cookieSession({secret: 'secret', key: 'express.sid', cookie:{ path: '/', httpOnly: true, maxAge: (1000*3600*24)} }));
    app.use(express.static('public'))
   .use(function (req, res) {
        res.end('File not available\n');
    });

function getUserName(socket) {
    var deferred = q.defer();
    socket.get('userName', function (err, Name) {
        if (err || !Name) { // PROBLEM: It always goes in to this IF
            var userName = "Userno: " + (userCounter + 1);
            userCounter++;
            socket.set('userName', userName, function () {
                deferred.resolve(userName);
            });
        } else {
            deferred.resolve(Name);
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    getUserName(socket).
        then(function (userName) {
            socket.emit("welcome", userName);
            _(io.sockets.sockets).forEach(function (eSocket) {
                if (socket !== eSocket)
                    eSocket.emit("userAdded", userName);
            });
            socket.on('disconnect', function () {
                socket.get('userName', function (err, userName) {
                    io.sockets.emit('userRem', userName);
                });
            });
        });

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't implemented any session authentication for your `socket.io`. By default every connection to your `socket.io` is a new connection, although it has the same cookie ( session_id in your cookie ). There is a [special option](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO) for `socket.io` to pass every request through authentication function something like:

```
var sAuthorization = function(req, cb) {
    if ( req.headers.cookie ) { 
        cb(null, true); return; // We have cookie
    } else {
        cb(null, false); return; // We don't have cookie drop the connection
    };

var socket = require('socket.io').listen(app, { authorization: sAuthorization });
```

Things you should do to make it work ( I will not write this as a code, becuase there are a lot of modifications needed ) :

1. Implement giving the user a name in your initial `http` connection within express ( every user should be given an username for their unique session );
2. Implement sessionStore which can be reached by express & socket.io ( see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/2266544) for some ideas how to do it ( it uses `nowjs` but it's the sessionStore code you have to look ). Actually it's better if you place your sessionStore in some database, not in your MemoryStore.
3. Make your `socket.io` authorization sub to reach this sessionStore and get the username, then place it as a parameter for this socket as usual : `socket.set('name', ....`

Pretty much that's it. It's not as hard as it sounds, but that's the proper way of doing this.

Further reading :

1. https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO
2. https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Authorizing

#### Update :

Look at this answer it will be very helpful for you
[Securing Socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14600472/securing-socket-io)

#### Update II :

I've created a Gist file here with that code https://gist.github.com/1b17fd2a7b324cb3411a

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    http = require('http'),
    server = http.createServer(app),
    users = 0,
    MemoryStore = express.session.MemoryStore,
    sessionStore = new MemoryStore(),
    parseCookie = require('cookie').parse,
    utils = require('connect').utils,
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

app.use( express.bodyParser() );
app.use( express.cookieParser('secret') );
app.use( express.session({secret: 'secret', store:sessionStore}) );

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var user = req.session.username ? req.session.username : null;
    if ( !user ) {
        user = 'user_' + users++;
        req.session.username = user;
        req.session.save();
    }
    res.send('<!doctype html> \
        <html> \
        <head><meta charset="utf-8"></head> \
        <body> \
            <center>Welcome ' + user + '</center> \
            <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> \
            <script> \
                var socket = io.connect(); \
                socket.emit("message", "Howdy"); \
            </script> \
        </body> \
        </html>');
});

io.configure(function () {
    io.set('authorization', function (request, callback) {
        var cookie = parseCookie(request.headers.cookie);
        if( !cookie && !cookie['connect.sid'] ) {
            return callback(null, false);
        } else {
            sessionStore.get(utils.parseSignedCookie(cookie['connect.sid'], 'secret'), function (err, session) {
                if ( err ) {
                    callback(err.message, false);
                } else {
                    if ( session && session.username ) {
                        request.user = session.username;
                        callback(null, true);
                    } else {
                        callback(null, false);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('message', function(msg) {
        console.log(msg + 'from '+ socket.handshake.user);
    });
});

server.listen(8000);
```

Comment: It can be extremely helpful, If you correct the code and provide it. Can you please do it?