# node.js (with socket.io) security?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, websocket, socket.io

since I am learning node.js I was wondering about something:
When I use node.js server to run a websocket, so that clients can connect (like on a website via javascript), it always listens public. Isn't that a security problem, that everyone in the world would be able to send data to the ip:port. They just have to connect to the server via the data that are written anyway within javascript and send / receive data?

I was thinking about a token, which would make sense in Java or Swift etc, but in javascript it can be seen anyway?!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Securing Socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14600472/securing-socket-io)

Comment: Yes, this is how the web works.  A Websocket is no different than an HTTP request in this regard.  If it can be reached by a browser, then it can be reached by any hacker who wants to.  You need to protect your service from abuse with things such as account logins, rate limiting, unauthorized use detection and such as Google does with its services.  And, this issue has nothing to do with the choice of back-end architecture.  You could be using .NET, any Java framework, PHP, Ruby, etc...  They'd all have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: yes, It's totally secure.
Every time the browser sends an HTTP request, there is a port waiting for the server's response. The difference between this to an open port is that an open port is open for everyone on the web. In an HTTP request or web socket, the port opens only to the server.