# Is it safe to use socket.io for register and log in users?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, angular, socket.io

in order to create a website that uses socket.io for communicating to the server is it safe to create a register and login part by socket.io instead of using Axios or etc. but I have doubt that it is safe if we use it or not?
be appreciated if you explain it.

Comment: Depends if your socket is running on `ws` or `wss`

Comment: Keith, I will use it through SSL protocol and it is definitely a WSS connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Socket.io and axios are both tools/methods to connect your app to a server. Both of them can be secured. Socket.io uses websocket, and axios is XHR based.

How to secure a Socket.io connection so that info like password are encrypted.
[Securing Socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14600472/securing-socket-io)

Managing registration/login can be hard and troublesome, you can always use something like Auth0.